# Why I cannot find some Javascript objects with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to read the `InitialChatFriendsList` from my Facebook profile with Selenium.
When I login into Facebook manually and display the page source I easily can find
the element. However, when I use Selenium I cannot find the string:

```
source = browser.page_source
print 'InitialChatFriendsList' in source 
# False
```

**Why I cannot find these Javascript elements?**

Comment: Searching an entire page for a string of text is just ridiculous and Selenium isn't even needed for this. Facebook has an extensive API, even for it's chat features, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/ ....

Comment: @Arran : Facebook's API can be a wonderful way to solve this issue. However, I would prefer to know why `Selenium` does not find these elements. Where are they? Why they are not part of the `page_source`? And how I can access these elements?

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not configure the javascript files in eclipse. So please remove all files java eclipse (selenium) files and configure the files newly.